# For each array in array in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have array like that :

```
[[[37.1316, 56.01645], [37.15117, 55.99955], [37.14439, 55.98932], [37.14661, 55.96372], [37.18212, 55.95873], [37.20565, 55.96284], [37.21284, 55.9766], [37.26641, 55.97947], [37.26056, 55.99314], [37.18898, 56.02122], [37.16173, 56.01322], [37.1316, 56.01645]]]
```

How I can use toFixed to get each item in array toFixed(2)?

On output I need like that :

```
[[[37.73, 55.87], [37.69, 55.89], [37.63, 55.89], [37.58, 55.91], [37.55, 55.90], [37.56, 55.94], [37.51, 55.94], [37.53, 55.90], [37.56, 55.89], [37.57, 55.86], [37.57, 55.83], [37.57, 55.82], [37.58, 55.79], [37.65, 55.78], [37.65, 55.80], [37.66, 55.82], [37.67, 55.83], [37.69, 55.84], [37.72, 55.85], [37.70, 55.86], [37.73, 55.87]]]
```

Comment: How would you do it if you had _just_ arrays in an array?

Comment: How would you do it - is my question =)

Comment: So you have an array of arrays of arrays.  You usually iterate with a for loop.  So you need a for loop of for loops of for loops.

Comment: Just use 3 nested `for` loops. This is beginner programming.

Comment: SO is not a tutoring service, you're expected to learn the basics yourself.

Comment: The output is not going to be like "that". Numbers in JavaScript do not come with a fixed number of decimals. You'd get an array of arrays of arrays of strings.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Array.prototype.map` to map over the inner array(s), and use `Number.prototype.toFixed` on the individual destructured floating point numbers you get.

Use `Array.prototype.reduce` to accumulate the processed result of the operation:

```js
const arr = [
  [
    [37.1316, 56.01645],
    [37.15117, 55.99955],
    [37.14439, 55.98932],
    [37.14661, 55.96372],
    [37.18212, 55.95873],
    [37.20565, 55.96284],
    [37.21284, 55.9766],
    [37.26641, 55.97947],
    [37.26056, 55.99314],
    [37.18898, 56.02122],
    [37.16173, 56.01322],
    [37.1316, 56.01645]
  ]
];


const data = arr.reduce((acc, innerArray) => {
  const t = innerArray.map(
    ([first, second]) => [first.toFixed(2), second.toFixed(2)]
  );
  acc.push(t);
  return acc;
}, []);
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `flat()` and `reduce()` as follows:

```js
const arr = [[[37.1316, 56.01645], [37.15117, 55.99955], [37.14439, 55.98932], [37.14661, 55.96372], [37.18212, 55.95873], [37.20565, 55.96284], [37.21284, 55.9766], [37.26641, 55.97947], [37.26056, 55.99314], [37.18898, 56.02122], [37.16173, 56.01322], [37.1316, 56.01645]]]

const res = [arr.flat(2).reduce((acc, curr, i, flatArr) => {

  if(i % 2 === 1) {
    acc.push([flatArr[i - 1].toFixed(2), curr.toFixed(2)]);
  }

  return acc;
}, [])];

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
const your_array = [[[37.73, 55.87], [37.69, 55.89], [37.63, 55.89], [37.58, 55.91], [37.55, 55.90], [37.56, 55.94], [37.51, 55.94], [37.53, 55.90], [37.56, 55.89], [37.57, 55.86], [37.57, 55.83], [37.57, 55.82], [37.58, 55.79], [37.65, 55.78], [37.65, 55.80], [37.66, 55.82], [37.67, 55.83], [37.69, 55.84], [37.72, 55.85], [37.70, 55.86], [37.73, 55.87]]]

your_array[0] = your_array[0].map((a) => [parseFloat(a[0].toFixed(2)), parseFloat(a[1].toFixed(2))])
console.log(your_array);
```

Comment: Data gonna be change to strings so you can add parseFloat to the `a[0].toFixed(2)` and `a[1].toFixed(2)`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but right now I think I clearly can not understand how it works. Can you please give example for console?

Comment: Why only `your_array[0]` instead of looping over all elements of `your_array`?

Comment: Cause he got 1 element of array that has array of arrays. This just for his example.

Answer (score -1):

Use Array.prototype.map to map over the inner array(s), and use Number.prototype.toFixed on the individual destructured floating point numbers you get.